# Prove a result in multiple linear regression

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics, regression

This arises in multiple linear regression.

Given $m, n \in \mathbb{N}$ and matrices $X \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times (n+1)} (m > n + 1), H = X(X'X)^{-1}X' \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times m}, I = I_m$ and $J \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times m}$, a matrix of $1$'s, how does one show that

$$J(I-H) = 0\text{ ?}$$

I am actually trying to show

$$(I-H)(H-\frac{1}{n}J) = 0$$

which reduces to $J(I-H) = 0$ by noting that $HH =H$.

Apparently, this might have something to do with $J(y - X \hat{\beta}) = 0 \ \forall y \in \mathbb{R}^{1\times(m+1)}$ where  $\hat{\beta} = (X'X)^{-1}X'y $?

Is the statement true? If so why? If not, why not, and how then to prove $J(I-H) = 0$ or $(I-H)(H-\frac{1}{n}J) = 0$? I think there's some property of MLR needed.

On the other hand, the equation $J(I-H) = 0$ itself looks like it is independent of statistics. Must one really use some properties of MLR? What are some possible counterexamples?

Comment: You shouldn't write $m\ x\ (n+1)$ if you mean $m\times(n+1)$.  I edited accordingly.

Comment: @MichaelHardy Didn't know that. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not true that $J(I-H)=0$ unless the rows of $J$, each of which is a row of $1$s, are in the row space of $X'$.  That will certainly happen if one of the columns of $X$ is a column of $1$s, as happens in typical multiple regression problems.  If you're not using the fact that one of the columns of $X$ is a column of $1$s, or failing that, that a column of $1$s is a linear combination of some of the columns of $X$, then you won't be able to prove this.

Note that $X'H=X'$, and hence for every column $X_j$ of $X$ we have $X_j'H=X_j'$.

Comment: Thanks Michael Hardy. First, X indeed has a column of 1's. How does that mean that J is in the column space? Actually, column space is a set of vectors right? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Column_space#Definition Second, what exactly is your point about HX = X? If JX - JHX = 0, I don't think it follows that J - JH = 0...

Comment: I didn't say $J$ is in the column space of $X$, but that its columns are in the column space of $X$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: The point about $HX=X$ is that every column of $X$ is fixed by the mapping $X_j\mapsto HX_j = X_j$.  Consequently if $X_j$ is a column of $1$s, then $HX_j$ is the same column of $1$s. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: I've revised the answer since you put $J$ on the left. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: So you mean $JH = [1^T ... 1^T]H = [1^T H ... 1^T H] = [1^T ... 1^T] = J$ ? Wait, how do you know that X'H = X?

Comment: That $X'H=X'$ follows almost instantly from the definition of $H$, thus: $X'H = X'\Big(X(X'X)^{-1}X'\Big)$ $=\Big(X'X\Big)(X'X)^{-1}X'$.  A matrix is multiplied by its inverse and they cancel. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Oh right it's like the HX = X. Thanks again XD